# How to draw lines in xz plane using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to draw a series of parallel lines in the xz plane, but can't find a sufficiently simple example.

I suspect my use of Geometry is somehow mistaken.

```
function initGrid(){
  var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  for(var i=0 ; i<10; i++){
    geometry.vertices.push(
      (10*i,0,0),  (10*i,0,100)
    );  
  }
  var grid = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, material);
  scene.add(grid); 
}
```

My thinking is that the geometry object given to LineSegments should consist of pairs of coordinates, representing the begin & end points of each line. The above function however, doesn't work.

Could anyone give a correct technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertices of `Geometry` are an array of `THREE.Vector3`.

```
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( x, y, z ) );
```

Also, you can use `THREE.GridHelper( size, divisions, color1, color2 )`.

three.js r.84